# Am I allowed to put single quoted, double quoted heredoc syntax or nowdoc syntax strings directly into a functions parameter that uses a string?

Tags: php

Am I allowed to put single quoted, double quoted heredoc syntax or nowdoc syntax strings directly into functions whose parameters require a string like for example `strlen('string text')` or `strlen("some more string text")` instead of including a variable for example `strlen($str);`?

If not why?

Comment: I tried the nowdoc and herdoc but no success.

Comment: heredoc works without problems, though it's a bit *tricky* (and unreadable), i.e., if you start it with `<<<STRING`, you can't end it with `STRING);` or `STRING, $otherParam`. You also cannot have any space before `STRING`. See lonesomeday's example, it works as expected.

Comment: There is no reason to do this though, it adds an unnecessary function call because the result will be the same every time.

Comment: @gnur, think again ;) String may contain variables with inconstant values, as well as `strlen()` might be given only for illustration, i.e., in reality, other functions might be used.

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to do that unless function expects string variable to be passed by reference:

```
// '&' means that argument is passed by reference
function requestStringAsVariable(&$str) {
    $str = '*' . $str . '*';
}

$str = 'test';
requestStringAsVariable($str);
echo $str; // outputs '*test*';

requestStringAsVariable('foo'); // won't work, as function expects variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any syntax for creating strings.

Note, however, that you have to be careful when using heredoc/nowdoc syntax with function calls: the final line of the string can't contain anything except the identifier:

```
var_dump(<<<HERE
foo
HERE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. You do not need to store it in a variable